# Python: soup/parser -> cannot find "div" by id

Tags: python, html, parsing

I cannot find anything inside "div" with id="bbOffers" (even this div) inside this page:
https://lubimyczytac.pl/ksiazka/5076165/futeral-o-urzadzaniu-mieszkan-w-prl-u

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://lubimyczytac.pl/ksiazka/5076165/futeral-o-urzadzaniu-mieszkan-w-prl-u"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", id="bbOffers"))
```

Even if I print all the text by `soup_text`, there is nothing what should be inside this "div" -> e.g. prices of books for different shops.

Is there a problem with my code or this page cannot be scpraped like this?

edit: I've try to add `time.sleep(10)` in every place in code (due to the fact that this part of code could be dynamically loaded) but it did not help.

Using this page I want to build calcuclator "where it will be cheapier to buy more than 1 book".

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because you're using `urllib` to fetch the page, which cannot process javascript.  You need to use something that acts like a real browser, such as selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via Javascript (so [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) doesn't see it).

You can use this example how to load the data using `requests`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://lubimyczytac.pl/ksiazka/5076165/futeral-o-urzadzaniu-mieszkan-w-prl-u"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data_url = soup.select_one("[data-buybox-url]")["data-buybox-url"]

data = requests.get(data_url).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "status": True,
    "data": {
        "https://go.buybox.click/bbclick_17929_190329922?p1=desktop&p2=5076165.0.": {
            "id": 190329922,
            "name": "tantis.pl",
            "icon": "https://assets.buybox.click/c1f2543f59c0240778e4c90fc4633cbc8e689267.png",
            "logo": "https://assets.buybox.click/e6e93a53778c0afe5d8bb33f55e52eb24294ece5.png",
            "type": "book",
            "typeId": 1,
            "typeName": "książka",
            "shopId": 52,
            "currency": "PLN",
            "price": "67.09",
            "bbWeight": 10,
        },
        "https://go.buybox.click/bbclick_17929_191160372?p1=desktop&p2=5076165.0.": {
            "id": 191160372,
            "name": "czytam.pl",
            "icon": "https://assets.buybox.click/d40e5071c4fb9fea8966516227f42132877bf7df.png",
            "logo": "https://assets.buybox.click/c4afd45c487e6b88a735d141a1ec10caba601f50.png",
            "type": "book",
            "typeId": 1,
            "typeName": "książka",
            "shopId": 183,
            "currency": "PLN",
            "price": "67.62",
            "bbWeight": 10,
        },

...
```